# Need to Group array of JSONs by Product. Display as comma separated products

Tags: javascript, json, arraylist

i'm new on it and i'm trying from this JSON array in Javascript

So i need to sort the "Name" by Product they were assigned

```
[
   {
      "Name":"Marcelo Rocha",
      "Product_Line__c":"SAP",
      "Role":"Regional Manager, SAP Support Delivery, LATAM"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Marcelo Rocha",
      "Product_Line__c":"Business Objects",
      "Role":"Regional Manager, SAP Support Delivery, LATAM"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Marcelo Rocha",
      "Product_Line__c":"Oracle Technology",
      "Role":"Regional Manager, SAP Support Delivery, LATAM"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Leonardo Gracioli",
      "Product_Line__c":"SAP",
      "Role":"Senior Support Engineer, SAP"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Leonardo Gracioli",
      "Product_Line__c":"Business Objects",
      "Role":"Senior Support Engineer, SAP"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Leonardo Gracioli",
      "Product_Line__c":"Oracle Technology",
      "Role":"Senior Support Engineer, SAP"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Adriane Yonamine",
      "Product_Line__c":"SAP",
      "Role":"SAP Consultant"
   }
]
```

Combine the "Name" by ProductLime in order to be like this:

```
[
   {
      "Name":"Marcelo Rocha",
      "Product_Line__c":"SAP,Business Objects,Oracle Technology",
      "Role":"Regional Manager, SAP Support Delivery, LATAM"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Leonardo Gracioli",
      "Product_Line__c":"SAP,Business Objects,Oracle Technology",
      "Role":"Senior Support Engineer, SAP"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Adriane Yonamine",
      "Product_Line__c":"SAP",
      "Role":"SAP Consultant"
   }
]
```

Please could anyone know an easier way to do it?

Comment: This is a regular javascript `Array` and has nothing to do with [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sortUsers(Role, arr) {
  let result = [];
  arr.filter(person => person.Product_Line__c === Role).forEach(person => {
     result.push({ Name: person.Name, Product_Line__c: arr.filter(obj => obj.Name === person.Name).map(obj => obj.Product_Line__c).join(','), Role: person.Role}) 
  });
  return result;
}

const arr = [
   {
      "Name":"Marcelo Rocha",
      "Product_Line__c":"SAP",
      "Role":"Regional Manager, SAP Support Delivery, LATAM"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Marcelo Rocha",
      "Product_Line__c":"Business Objects",
      "Role":"Regional Manager, SAP Support Delivery, LATAM"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Marcelo Rocha",
      "Product_Line__c":"Oracle Technology",
      "Role":"Regional Manager, SAP Support Delivery, LATAM"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Leonardo Gracioli",
      "Product_Line__c":"SAP",
      "Role":"Senior Support Engineer, SAP"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Leonardo Gracioli",
      "Product_Line__c":"Business Objects",
      "Role":"Senior Support Engineer, SAP"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Leonardo Gracioli",
      "Product_Line__c":"Oracle Technology",
      "Role":"Senior Support Engineer, SAP"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Adriane Yonamine",
      "Product_Line__c":"SAP",
      "Role":"SAP Consultant"
   }
];

console.log(sortUsers("SAP", arr));
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, I would appreciate it if you marked a letter as the correct answer

Comment: Your code is elegant but seems to rely on the `Role`  property containing the _magic_ string "SAP"

Comment: Absolutely not, my code relies on `Product_Line__c` -->
`arr.filter(person => person.Product_Line__c === Role)`

Comment: Apologies, I gave a bad description.  The Role parameter is set to "SAP" which you are using to produce a unique list of names. I think you should be able to produce a unique list of names without having to rely on that string

Comment: This is what I understood the OP to ask, if I'm wrong correct me and I'll edit my answer :)

Comment: It produces the correct output so it's not wrong. The OP didn't really show anything they tried so maybe you just offered a quick solution.  I just saw two points in your code that could be reworked to not rely on hard coded values and so I tailored my answer around that. Cheers.

Comment: `So i need to sort the "Name" **by Product** they were assigned`

Comment: Did you notice that neither of us are actually sorting?  To `sort the Name by Product they were assigned` _should_ change the order to _Adriene, Marcelo, Leonardo_ Or even _Adriene, Leonardo, Marcelo_ if the sort takes the Name into account.

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait for the OP to show up to explain exactly his question lol

Comment: True :) still going to mod my answer tho. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Haim Abeles answer as it's very elegant, but it also seems to rely on `Product_Line__c` containing the word "SAP" (Role parameter to `sortUsers()` )

I have a much more verbose, less elegant code explaining what going on.

##### Update: Added final sort

```js
const arr = [{
    "Name": "Marcelo Rocha",
    "Product_Line__c": "SAP",
    "Role": "Regional Manager, SAP Support Delivery, LATAM"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Marcelo Rocha",
    "Product_Line__c": "Business Objects",
    "Role": "Regional Manager, SAP Support Delivery, LATAM"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Marcelo Rocha",
    "Product_Line__c": "Oracle Technology",
    "Role": "Regional Manager, SAP Support Delivery, LATAM"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Leonardo Gracioli",
    "Product_Line__c": "SAP",
    "Role": "Senior Support Engineer, SAP"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Leonardo Gracioli",
    "Product_Line__c": "Business Objects",
    "Role": "Senior Support Engineer, SAP"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Leonardo Gracioli",
    "Product_Line__c": "Oracle Technology",
    "Role": "Senior Support Engineer, SAP"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Adriane Yonamine",
    "Product_Line__c": "SAP",
    "Role": "SAP Consultant"
  }
];

// new home for results
let combinedResults = [];

// Obtain an arrayOfUniqueNames
var arrayOfUniqueNames = [...new Set(arr.map(x => x.Name))];

// Iterate through the list
arrayOfUniqueNames.forEach(name => {

  // filter through the source array 
  // to get an arrayOfObjectsForThisName
  let arrayOfObjectsForThisName = arr.filter((obj) => obj.Name === name);

  // Create a productLinesCSVForThisName
  let productLinesCSVForThisName = arrayOfObjectsForThisName.map(el => el.Product_Line__c).join();

  // Clone the first object in the source array and replace
  // property Product_Line__c with productLinesCSVForThisName
  let aSourceObjToClone = arr.find(o => o.Name === name);
  let aClonedSOurceObject = Object.assign({}, aSourceObjToClone);
  aClonedSOurceObject.Product_Line__c = productLinesCSVForThisName;

  // Push the newly created object into the combinedResults array
  combinedResults.push(aClonedSOurceObject);
});

console.log(combinedResults.sort((a, b) => {
  // Sort By Product Line only
  return a.Product_Line__c.localeCompare(b.Product_Line__c);

  /* Or Sort by Product then Name
  let value =  a.Product_Line__c.localeCompare(b.Product_Line__c);
  
  if( value === 0 ) 
    value = a.Name.localeCompare( b.Name);
    
  return value;
  */
}));
```